# TCL how to shorten sentence

Tags: string, range, tcl

I have a sentence let's say :
{This is my test sentence}
And I would like to shorten by 3 characters at the end like this :
{This is my test sente}

Here is what I do in TCL language :

```
set sentence "This is my test sentence"
set remove "3"
set newSentence [string range $sentence 0 end-$remove]
```

and here is what I get :
"This"

I've tried with

```
set sentence {This is my test sentence}
```

and it is even worth because I got an error message
"failed: unmatched open brace in list"

Can someone have an idea where I am wrong ?
Or may be how I can shorten a string whatever spaces inside it ?
Thank you by advance for your help

Comment: Strange - when I try your code I get the desired result.  The results you report suggest that you are using list operations (`lrange`) rather than string operations (`string range`), but that does not match the code you show. 

Answer (score -2):

Finally got it, I had to force it as a list :

```
set newSentence [list [string range $sentence 0 end-$remove]]
```

It seems my engine over interprete the output value.

Comment: No, this is not necessary.   The `string range` command gets evaluated by the interpreter first and would not be affected by being enclosed by a `list` command.

Comment: There is clearly something else going on that vech is not showing us.

Comment: If there is something else I am not showing this is not deliberately (what could it be ?). But I can ensure you as soon as I add this list I was able to see my string as expected.

Comment: Please re-read your original post and the comments.  It's confusing because you are saying the `set newSentence [string range $sentence 0 end-$remove]` doesn't work...but it really does work just fine.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion but ```[string range $sentence 0 end-$remove]``` doesn't work when ```[list [string range $sentence 0 end-$remove]]``` does work, in MY case. Anyway as I solved my issue may be I can just delete this entry to don't create this unwanted confusion, it was just about sharing my experience.