# TCL string map with a "\ "

Tags: string, dictionary, escaping, tcl, whitespace

I have a phone number like `012.345.67.89` and I need to change it to `012\ 345\ 67\ 89`
Because I don't want a list but a string.

I've tried

```
set out [string map [list . {\ }] $in]
set out [string map [list . "\\ "] $in]
```

But I only get
`{012 345 67 89}`
and not
`012\ 345\ 67\ 89`
Can someone help me to find a way to put litteraly the
`\`  (with the whitespace).
I even try with `regsub` with no success.
The problem here, is that I can't split and join easily because it could be a foreign phone number with random length...
Thank you by advance for your help :)

Comment: I don't see any problem with what you've tried.  

If your map argument was `[list . "\ "]` then you would not get a literal `\ ` but your two solutions properly define a literal `\ `.  

By the way, Tcl doesn't have types.   Any variable has a string representation.  Any variable can act like a list in list commands provided that its string forms a proper list.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I miss something on my environment then...

Comment: Please give some details about your environment.     I realized that you also asked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72111008/tcl-how-to-shorten-sentence/72111691#72111691 six months ago where your Tcl code seemed fine, but you said it wasn't working as expected.    Which version of Tcl are you running?   How exactly are you testing your code?

Comment: I work on Cloverleaf environment, with multiple versions, so there are some over interpreted actions as tcl is just a part of the alogrithm